# plot a function in the positive semi axes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good morning,
I would like to plot the following function: x=60-(1/6)*y. This function I'd like to be presented only in the positive side of both axes. How can I achive this? Is there a package or any order on how can I have any function plotted? I have tried many things seen both in this site and in others but I haven't succeded yet in making a good looking figure.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What things have you tried? PGFPlots? If so, could you show your code and explain why you're not happy with the result?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Sorry my function was: y=60-(1/6)*x and the code i've tried was:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=14, yscale=4]
\draw[thick, <->](0,0.8)--(0,0)--(0.5,0);
\draw[blue, domain=0:.5] plot (\x, {60-\x/6});
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: \end{document} forgot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments before, you can use the great package `pgfplots` for this.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=360,ymin=0]
\addplot [domain=0:360,blue] {60-x/6};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots plot as stated above, clipped with preview]

But I can't really recomend plotting a simple function like this. It is easy enough to read, the ink to information ratio is not to well. If you want further information on ink to information ratio I suggest reading something written by Edward Tufte. Alternatively I would recommend the TikZ manual. pgfplots is build on TikZ.
If there is a good reason to still do it: Happy TeXing!